# is one version of javascript in two formats equivalent?

Tags: javascript

Need to flatten a javascript into a single string in order to insert it into several pages. "Flatten" means remove all newlines.

Have this JS for Google Analytics:

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Is this equivalent?

```
<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');</script>
```

Can I further remove white space after a comma? Are there cases where white space means something in a javascript?

Comment: The only space that cannot be removed from the code is in `new Date`.

Comment: I don't see a problem on having the whole script in a single line. Unless you'll try to debug it afterwards (same issue with minified files).

Comment: Are you doing this by hand? If so, you should check out JSMin (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) or YUI (http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) or a myriad of other JS minifiers.

Comment: @artjom B. Very good to know - something I would have missed in reading JS documentation and looking at similar answer. TY.

Comment: You would need to preserve whitespace in strings and regular expressions, if your script included strings and regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can remove a white-space after a comma and this will change nothing.

Instead of doing this manually, you should consider using a JavaScript minifier such as [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write it all in one line! It will not affect the browser, remove the spaces after commas and stuff, just don't remove any space which is necessary even for multi line. The purpose of writing it in multi line with indentation is to make it more **Human Readable**. Browser will just parse it whatever way it is written in as long as it is syntactically correct.